# CSS span within a link

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I'm a developer and my design skills are minimal at the minute, I'm working on a personal site and I'm stuck with a minor issue.

I have a top nav with a `ul` and `li` items. These items contain link `<a href...` and within these tags I have a `<span>`.

The span only displays when the link is hover over.

**CSS**

```
div#topnav a span {display: none;}
div#topnav a:visited span {display:none;}
div#topnav a:hover span {display: block;}
```

The problem is, the span has quite a bit of text in, and when it displays it makes the link width large, thus pushing the rest of the top nav to the right.

Is there something I can do to tell the a tag to ignore the spans width and not change when the span is displayed but not affect the width being automatically set by the links text (non span)?

**HTML**

```
<div id="topnav">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Example<span>this is a link to google</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Another EG<span>this is another link that goes to bbc!</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

It's worth noting, this text in the span appears below the nav, so I need it all to be displayed.

Comment: put a `width: 10em; overflow: hidden; display: block` on the span, so you can limit its width and hide the overflow.

Comment: Yeh, I've added an example of what I'm using to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you want you can simply remove the span out of the flow and they will stop affecting the links in any way by just giving an absolute position to the span and a relative position to the a. You also don't need the :visited I think, since I'm guessing that it will prevent the link from showing up if already visited. Like this:

```
div#topnav a {position:relative;}
div#topnav a span {display: none;}
div#topnav a:visited span {color:purple;}
div#topnav a:hover span {display: block;postion:absolute;bottom:-50px;}
```

You can change the bottom value to fit your needs, or add left/right properties to position them further. You may consider adding a width to the span as well. position:relative on the a is required so that the span will know from where to go 50 px downwards.

*Edit: added the visited class, since it may help the ux to a degree by just changing the text color.*

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a width on the span/link so that it won't automatically determine it by the length of the content.

```
div#topnav a span { width: 50px; }
```

Note: `50px` is an example, you can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: My text then goes on to multiple lines, I want it to still all display as it is still below the nav. Just don't want the link in the nav to push the other nav items along.

Answer (score 0):

Try using div tag outside "a" tag which has fixed width so that your content doesnt go across the specified width.